# I want to delete a post but having errors that i can't seems to figure out. How do i delete a data from database with DELETE?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, mongoose, http-delete

HERE ARE TWO ERRORS THAT I'M GETTING.

```
MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{item._id}" at path "_id" for model "Post"
```

Second One

```
  stringValue: '"{item._id}"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
 value: '{item._id}',
 path: '_id',


reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

My Index.js

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/postcomment", {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PostSchema = new Schema({
   title: String,
   content: String,
   author: String
});

var Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);


router.delete( '/post/:id', function( req, res ){
   let query = {_id:req.params.id}

  Post.deleteOne(query, function(err) {
    if(err){
   console.log(err);
   }
  res.send('Success');
 });
});
```

My Delete button

```
<a class="delete-article" href="#" data-id="{item._id}">Delete</a>
```

My main.js File

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.delete-article').on('click', function(e) {
   const $target = $(e.target);
    const id = $target.attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/post/'+id,
        success: function(response) {
            alert('Deleting Post');
            window.location.href='/';
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}); 
[![This is a snapshot of the error message][1]][1]});
```

My `View`

```
<% items.forEach(item => { %>
<ul>
    <h1><%=item.title%></h1>
    <li><%= item.content %></li>
    <li><%= item.author %></li>
    <a class="delete-article" href="#" data-id="{item.id}">Delete</a>

  </ul>
<% });%>
<li><a href="/newpost">Add New Post</a></li>
```

I am new to Node and Javascript and i am trying to build something as a way of learning. but i have ran into an error that has kept me trying for hours without success. please i need a help to fix this error.

I am trying to keep it `CRUD`, so i'm using `delete` to delete a post from the database.
The errors that i am getting is referring to `ObjectId` and `passing a single string of 12` bite, i have tried but didn't succeed. please i will appreciate any help to fix this and also explanation to help me understand it.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the documents id but you pass {item._id} , 
try to fix your `data-id="{item._id}"` to pass the actual _id .
Check at your router the id param you send from the browser

```
router.delete( '/post/:id', function( req, res ){
    // check the id if it is valid
    console.log(req.params.id)
   let query = {_id:req.params.id}

  Post.deleteOne(query, function(err) {
    if(err){
   console.log(err);
   }
  res.send('Success');
 });
});
```

What template engine you are using ?

Comment: I am using `ejs` I have also updated my post to include the view

Comment: I Checked the `Id params` on the console.log and this is what it returned `{item._id}
`

Comment: so i changed the data-id into this `data-id="<%= item.id%>"` and it's now working. Wow, you guys are amazing, thank for all the helps i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

you can try this maybe the id you are passing from frontend is not in ID format

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;


 router.delete( '/post/:id', function( req, res ){
   // check the id if it is valid
    console.log(req.params.id)
    let query = {_id:new ObjectId(req.params.id)}

    Post.deleteOne(query, function(err) {
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
             }
        res.send('Success');
       });
     });
```